# auto center <div><div></div></div>

Tags: html, css, center

I have a div (container I think?) I want that to be center page.

```html
<div style="margin: 0 auto;">
<div style="float: left; width: 300px;"><img src="owngfx/bankover.jpg" width="300" height="215" /></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 300px;">Billede 2</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 300px;">
<div class="fb-page" data-width="300" adapt_container_width="true" data-height="450" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/dagenshug" data-small-header="false" data-hide-cta="false" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="false">
<div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I just want all the context to go center page, how is that possible?

Comment: That code hurts to look at. Try using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:60%;">
<div style="float: left; width: 300px;"><img src="owngfx/bankover.jpg" width="300" height="215" /></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 300px;">Billede 2</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 300px;">
<div class="fb-page" data-width="300" adapt_container_width="true" data-height="450" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/dagenshug" data-small-header="false" data-hide-cta="false" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="false">
<div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

update the first line with an additional style width:x% as per your requirements

Comment: But if i put a width on that container, it will not be diaplayed right on smartphone ... and if i add 900px then it is shoed correct on laptop, but not on telephone

Comment: avoid using hard coding like "width:300px" try to use percentage. Or simply use bootstrap for responsiveness

Comment: Or use a media query: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: i got it to work..

i removed the 300px, and added 87% to the container ;)

Thanks for u help

Answer (score 0):

You need to display a **width** for the 'container' to centre it, as well as what you have done setting the left and right margins to `auto`.

Change your first line to this:

```
<div style="width: 50%; margin: 0px auto;">
```